# Password protected ZIP file - How to bypass the password successfully

Tags: windows, zip, passwords, php-ziparchive, cracking

I have a zip file which is password protected and in which I dont have any clue at all about the password.

I need to know if anyone of you have recently actually managed to open up a password protected zip file, either through online web based services or by some free and open source software you have downloaded?

In that case I would be extremely thankful for any advice, link, tutorial that would describe the proven method of bypassing password step-by-step. I am using Windows 10 in case it would help.

Thank you